# Confused on proof that every group of order $p^2$, $p$ prime is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

Every group of order $p^2$, $p$ prime is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p}$

I am confused about two parts of this proof.

Proof:Assume every nonidentity element of this group $G$ has order $p$. Then $\langle a\rangle$ is normal otherwise there is an element $b$ in $G$ such that $bab^{-1} \notin \langle a\rangle$

Here is my first source of confusion. if $\langle a\rangle$ is not normal I would suspect there is an element $b$ in $G$ with $ba^{i}b^{-1} \notin \langle a\rangle,\text{for some}\space i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Why does $bab^{-1} \notin \langle a\rangle$ necessarily hold with $a$?

Next part of confusion
Since $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle bab^{-1}\rangle =\{1\}$ the distinct left cosets of $\langle bab^{-1}\rangle$ are $\langle bab^{-1}\rangle,a\langle bab^{-1}\rangle,...,a^{p-1}\langle bab^{-1}\rangle$

is this because there must be $p$ distinct cosets and there union must be $G$, so this must be all of the cosets ?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` instead of `<` and `>`.

Comment: And don’t put the indices and math symbols in blackboard bold.

Comment: If $bab^{-1}\in\langle a\rangle$, then $ba^ib^{-1}=(bab^{-1})^{i}\in\angle a\rangle$. So $\langle a\rangle$ is normal if and only if for every $b$, $bab^{-1}\in\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: In standard mathematicians' English, one says "Every group of order $p^2,$" not "Every group order $p^2.$" $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, note that $\langle a\rangle$ is disjoint from $\langle bab^{-1}\rangle$ (except for the identity) if it is different by Lagrange's theorem. Thus, if $ba^ib^{-1}\notin \langle a\rangle$ for any $i$, the same is true of $a$, because $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle bab^{-1}\rangle=\{1\}$.

The reason all of those cosets are distinct is because coset $i$ contains $a^i$, which none of the others contain. By cardinality, since there are $p$ disjoint cosets it must be all of them.

Answer (score 4):

Alternate proof: The center of a $p$-group is nontrivial.  Then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic $\implies G$ is abelian.